# Is there any minimum sentence faced by SBF?

Tags: united-states, federal-courts, sentencing, current-events

The widely reported maximum sentence available faced by Bankman Fried is 115 years. Is there any minimum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Matthew Bultman, "[Bankman-Fried’s Pre-Trial Antics Haunt Him Before Sentencing](https://news.bloomberglaw.com/securities-law/bankman-frieds-pre-trial-antics-haunt-him-before-sentencing-1)" (3 November 2023):

> Judges are required to consider federal guidelines at sentencing, but don’t have to follow them.
>
> ...
>
> The low end of the sentencing guidelines could be 30 years in prison, depending in part on how much of the financial loss the judge finds can be attributed to Bankman-Fried.